# Popular as propriedades de uma classe

Tags: c#

Uma dúvida. Antes o serviço retornava valores na seguinte assinatura: **Previsto/Realizado**, isso facilitava bastante. Agora a assinatura mudou para isso:

```
{
        "CorIndicador":"VERMELHO",
        "DadosIndicador":"{\"Previsto\":25784.686452608872,\"Realizado\":95258.9557949728}",
        "TipoIndicador":1
    }
```

com a assinatura anterior a classe IndicadorItem que era assim:

```
public string Nome { get; set; }
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

agora com a nova assinatura, pois entrou dois novos campos **CorIndicador** e **TipoIndicador**. Como eu faria para popular a classe?

```
public class IndicadorData : List<IndicadorItem>
{}
```

assim eu deserealizo

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KpiResponse>(response.Content);
```

essa é a classe Kpi

```
[DataContract]
    public class KpiResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public TipoIndicador TipoIndicador { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DadosIndicador { get; set; }
    }
```

após deserealizar na classe kpi, faço assim para pegar os **DadosIndicador**

```
var fat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaturamentoResponse>(resp.DadosIndicador);
```

essa é a classe **FaturamentoResponse**

```
public class FaturamentoResponse
    {
        public double Previsto { get; set; }
        public double Realizado { get; set; }
    }
```

é exatamente isso que eu tenho. O que deveria fazer nesse caso para popular essa classe(IndicadorItem)? Do jeito que tá não dá. Qual melhor caminho para isso?

**EDIT1**

eu alterei a classe IndicadorData acrescentando o campo CorIndicador e no momento de consumir o Serviço, no `switch..case` eu faço isso:

```
var fat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaturamentoResponse>(resp.DadosIndicador);
                    res.CorIndicador = resp.CorIndicador;
                    res.Add(new IndicadorItem { Nome = "Realizado", Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(fat.Realizado) });
                    res.Add(new IndicadorItem { Nome = "Previsto", Valor = Convert.ToDecimal(fat.Previsto) });
```

Comment: Esse Json é só isso mesmo, ou é uma lista disso? se for uma lista coloque o exemplo na pergunta!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, é só isso mesmo o json. Ele vem dessa forma mesmo, só varia os valores, mas é isso apenas.

Comment: Você quer um exemplo para consumir esse `json`?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo de classe para carregar as informações desse retorno [json](/questions/tagged/json):

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
    public Dadosindicador DadosIndicador { get; set; }
    public int TipoIndicador { get; set; }
}

public class Dadosindicador
{
    public decimal Previsto { get; set; }
    public decimal Realizado { get; set; }
}
```

porque, o seu `Dadosindicador` é um objeto com dois campos do tipo `decimal`:

```
Rootobject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Se quiser facilitar a criação dessas classes pode utilizar o seguinte meio:

Crie uma arquivo `.cs` em branco, selecione o contéudo [json](/questions/tagged/json) copiando para a memória e depois no menu `Edit :: Paste Especial :: Paste JSON As Classes` clique para ser criado dentro desse arquivo `.cs` as classes referente ao `Layout` desse `json`, ***exemplo***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não são dois campos, em realidade eu tenho uma **List<IndicadorItem>** com Nome(string) e Valor(decimal), isto a classe IndicadorItem. A classe FaturamentoResponse sim, são dois campos, mas eu a uso apenas para deserializar o json do DadosIndicador.

Comment: O seu `Json` @pnet é assim que faz quando você nos proponhem um layout de json... e realmente não entendi o que precisa, porque, como já dito pelo `Json` é assim. O que precisa?

Comment: O seu `Json` são duas propriedades sim @pnet ... não é uma lista não, pelo menos o que está na pergunta